# Reading in multiple data types from a text file into a class object C++

Tags: c++, types, text-files

I have a text file of prisoner records:

Roy MOYES ARSON 35

Damien SIEBERT OTHER 37

Nigel COMYN ROBBERY 46 59000

Gai CRABBE OTHER 95

Stacey BEGLEY OTHER 80

I am trying to read this into a class object of prisoner:

```
void Prison::ReadCrimFile(){
ifstream fin;
fin.open("crims.txt");
if(!fin.good())
    cerr << "File not found!\n" << endl;
else
    while(!fin.eof()){
        fin >> FirstName >> FamilyName >> Crime >> Months;
        Criminal* C = new Criminal(FirstName, FamilyName, Crime, Months, i);
        Crims.insert(C);
    }
    fin.close();
    cout << "There are" << " " << Crims.size() << " " <<"criminals on 
record" << endl;
}
```

When I run it though it doesn't produce any output at the end, there's just blinking cursor in the console window

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: Your input stream is stalled on unexpected (missing) input. You never check if `fin >> FirstName >> FamilyName >> Crime >> Months;` went OK.